# remove quotes from criteria params

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.15 and am adding a criteria to my dataprovider

```
$search_condition[] = 'd.test IN (:pTEST)';
$search_params[':pTEST'] = $_GET[$key];

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('MODELNAME', 
                    array(
                        'criteria' => array(
                            'condition'=>$_search_conditions, 
                            'params'=>$search_params,
                        ),
    ));
```

Query generated is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TABLE` `s` 
WHERE (s.id IN (:pTEST)). Bound with :pTEST='6,50'
```

Which give me 0 results in my view when i call this function `$dataProvider->getTotalItemCount());`

but when i change my params to this. it works.

```
$search_condition[] = 'd.test IN ('.$_GET[$key].')';
```

won't this be vulnerable to mysql injections? if so, how do i use yii's params? Or should i just add a `mysql_real_escape_string`? Personally i would rather use Yii's bound if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an CDBCriteria class in yii which helps you in building the query

```
$values = explode(",",$_GET[$key])
$criteria = new CDBCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('test',$values)

$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('MODELNAME', 
                    array(
                        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
```

This would give you the required output

Comment: the params are set in the `criteria` too?

Comment: yes, but then it will work, you should not be doing with out params it will cause sql injections